# UISplitViewController: How to derive detail view's width in pixels programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

`<detailView>.view.frame.size.width` returns 768px, which is true for portrait but not landscape. How do I programmatically derive the width of detail view so I can layout its children views appropriately? I don't want to use hard-coded values

Comment: Did you try calling that method when it is in landscape? Because it should give you the correct width when you do that.

Comment: Yes, I called in while in landscape, both on device and emulator

Answer (score 3):

I've found out that `<DetailViewController>.navigationController.view.frame.size.width` works accurately for determining width in landscape mode.

Comment: For some reason `self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height` was off by 44 pixels, but this might be from the area occupied by the navigation bar itself.